# In react-slick, className doesn't match with class names in CSS files converted by webpack css-loader

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

I'm very new to `react-slick`. I've followed the installation instruction, but the slider doesn't come with CSS styles. My React project was created by create-react-app.

`slick.css` and `slick-theme.css` are imported styles.scss which is a file that I made to import the slick CSS files. As you see my css-loader set up in webpack.config.js, class names are supposed to be changed following `localIdentName`.

Because of that, the class names are converted in CSS, and my class names in HTML stay the same. Therefore, they don't match. How can I match them?

**webpack.config.dev.js**

```
test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
  use: [
    require.resolve("style-loader"),
    {
      loader: require.resolve("css-loader"),
      options: {
        importLoaders: 1,
        modules: true,
        localIdentName: "[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]",
        camelCase: "dashes"
      }
    },
    ...
```

**styles.scss**

```
@import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
@import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";
...
```

Comment: are u importing styles from node modules folder?

Comment: Yes, I just updated my original posting to add my `styles.scss` and elatorate `webpack.config.js`. As you see it, any CSS files or SCSS files are converted by css-loader. However, the problem is how I can make HTML tags to match with them in class names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your style.scss files put this

```
:global {
    @import 'node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick';
}
```

Adding `:global` will prevent css modules from renaming them

Comment: Is there a way to use `:global` for CSS files? It works for SCSS files, but not for CSS files. So, I just used `:global` for SCSS files, but it throws the error `Can't resolve './ajax-loader.gif'`

Comment: @Jay, did u import the theme file also?

Comment: Yes, I did `slick.scss` and `slick-theme.scss`, and actually `slick`theme.scss` file throws the error. By the way, I thought I'm thinking just to copy slick library files and paste them in my project folder. Would it be okay?

Comment: @jay, yes its okay, considering  the css files hardly gets updated on github.last update was a year ago. Or you can directly put the css cdn link in your html file